# Is there a way to extend existing signature?

Tags: ligo

I have a question regarding new module signatures. Is there a way to extend existing signature?

```
module type S1 = sig
  type t
  val v : t
end

module type S2 = sig
  include S1
  val v2 : t
end

module M : S2 = struct
  type t = nat
  let v = 1n
  let v2 = 2n
end
```

And any recommendation how to solve the following problem:
if module M does not implement any signature all its members including  `v2`  are public and can be accessed:

```
module M = struct
  type t = nat
  let v = 1n
  let v2 = 2n
end

....
let a = M.v2
```

But if it implements `S1` , all members not declared by `S1` are not visible outside the module:

```
module M : S1 = struct
  type t = nat
  let v = 1n
  let v2 = 2n
end

....
let a = M.v2 (* v2 cannot be accessed *)
```

Question from Dev Slack - Eugene Mishura

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no way of extending signatures yet.
There's an MR introducing `include`: https://gitlab.com/ligolang/ligo/-/merge_requests/2629 -> but for now, it handles `module` only, and not `module type`.

Regarding the question, `how to solve the following problem: if module M does not implement any signature all its members including v2 are public and can be accessed:`

Perhaps you can alias w.r.t. different module interfaces?

```
module type S1 = sig
  type t
  val v : t
end

module type S2 = sig
  type t
  val v : t
  val v2 : t
end

module M = struct
  type t = nat
  let v = 1n
  let v2 = 2n
end

module M1 : S1 = M

module M2 : S2 = M

let a = M1.v2 (* invalid *)
let b = M2.v2 (* valid *)
```